# How could we improve or increase spring connection handling capacity on the server side for any web or application server?

Tags: java, spring

If we handle HTTP request on the server side using spring framework, then how can we check that connection limit and how to increase its connection handling capacity. If any one have solution please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP connection handling depends on the configuration of the web/application server.
For example in Tomcat in server.xml, following parameters of HTTP IO/NIO Connectors can configure the number of connections server can handle.

1. **maxConnections** - The maximum number of connections that the server will accept and process at any given time. When this number has been reached, the server will accept, but not process, one further connection. This additional connection be blocked until the number of connections being processed falls below maxConnections at which point the server will start accepting and processing new connections again.
2. **acceptorThreadCount** - The number of threads to be used to accept connections. More than 2 is not required in multicore machines.

Other parameters which affect the same - **connectionLinger**, **connectionTimeout** etc.

For more details check [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: Thank's for this suggestion and I have one more query, can we increase at run time on our own program in spring if it possible.